# WinMerge says two files are identical when doing a diff on the directory, but comparing the files shows differences

Tags: diff, winmerge

I have two folders on my desktop, `PreChanges` and `PostChanges`.

`PostChanges` contains a few more files than `PreChanges`, but otherwise everything in one appears in the other.

If I use WinMerge to compare these two directories, including subfolders, it tells me only 4 documents are different. Here is a screenshot if it saying a particular file is Identicial:

[image]

But if I double click on it to diff that file specifically:

[image]

We can plainly see they are not identical.

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

WinMerge has a number of options that affect how it compares files. They are listed under `Edit > Options` and under `Tools > Filters`.

Under `Options` you can for instance set set that WinMerge compares files only on size. So your change from `50` to `10` would then not be picked up.

Maybe one of these options is masking your diffs. WinMerge will report that the files are identical, according to the criteria set in `Options`. The file diffs will however be shown when you open the files in WinMerge.

Under `Filters` you can enter regular expressions for patterns to ignore.

Maybe some patterns are still in there; a result of previous compare operations.

Answer (score 0):

What is your file encoding? WinMerge seems pretty buggy with Unicode - it could be this.

See:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/bugs/1930/
- http://forums.winmerge.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=178

Here are some alternatives, which may also solve the problem!

- https://www.freefilesync.org/
- http://meldmerge.org/

(I'm not affiliated with these products in any way, but they come up often on developer lists)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the comparison method:
Wrench icon / Compare Methods

It was set for date/size not Full contend